# Can an iPad become damaged by leaving it in a bathroom during and after a shower?

Tags: ipad, damage

I leave my iPad Mini 3 in my bathroom most of the time. If you must know, I enjoy reading my iPad while using the toilet.

I take daily showers in this bathroom. Showering produces steam and increases the humidity in the bathroom. I run the bathroom fan after showering for about 10 minutes, like one should, to remove much of the humidity.

The bathroom is very small. While I never actually spill water on my iPad, I'm sure that it is exposed to the moist air.

Can this moist air damage the iPad?

Can the moist air find its way *inside of* the iPad, resulting in the formation of condensation inside of the iPad? I'm sure that the iPad was not designed to have water inside of it.

The bottom line: Is it necessary to remove the iPad from the bathroom every time that I shower?

Comment: Ummm ... don't leave it in the bathroom when you shower? Water and iPads don't mix. There will be that one time when it does get splashed, or drop into the toilet, or fly into the shower when you are in it. Things happen. Its worth a few seconds to leave it outside the bathroom door (unless you worry it'll disappear while you're showering.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take shower while my electronics are in the bathroom, and I've never had a problem. I also don't do any of what I've said below.

There's no verifiable easy way (for me at least) to answer this question with proof. If you'd like to minimize the likelihood of moisture damage and you don't want to remove the iPad from the bathroom (or you can't) there are three things I can think of that might help:

- Plug something into the headphone jack. That's what's most likely to cause a failure in the iPad from moisture.
- Placing the iPad close to (but not on) the floor. The warm, moist air from the shower will collect at near the ceiling first.
- Avoid rapid temperature shifts when leaving the bathroom. If the iPad does have some moist air trapped, the shift to a cooler area will cause the moisture in the air to condense into liquid water.

Answer (score 1):

I am reading this question on an iPad Mini 4 in the shower. I have been taking it into showers with me everyday for several months with no ill effects. I keep it at eye level using a 3M Command little metal shelf that is attached to the shower wall opposite from where the water comes out. It gets a little wet from when I touch the screen with wet hands. So far, so good (no issues).

It is pretty cool. I started using it mainly to play podcasts while I shower. I also use the camera as a mirror to shave, and it is sometimes nice to have access to a clock from in there as well.

Comment: LOL
That's the best thing I've seen on this site 

Comment: I will add that my iPhone 12 Pro has had problems from being in the shower. This is probably because the screen is very cracked/damaged, which might be allowing more water to get in. So far, the Face ID has permanently disabled itself, and the screen went totally black for an entire day, then came back to life. Since that, I have stopped taking it in the shower, but haven't seen problems from just being in the bathroom.

Answer (score 0):

Dont ever leave your electronics in bathroom, I was listening to music while showering and my ipad was so far away from me now my ipad has this weird glitches and it wont turn on. Do not take risk